# How to link lapack with CMake and Visual 2013?

Tags: c++, linker, cmake, intel, lapack

***Abstract :*** I created a simple c++ example using lapack. I can't compile it with CMake and Visual Studio 2013 due to a link error.

**Configuration :** Windows 7 64-bit, Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64, Compiler intel64, CMake 3.1.0, Lapack 3.5.0.

**Lapack installation :** I built lapack 3.5.0 with CMake, using the compilers from intel. I activated all the BUILD_* options except BUILD_SHARED_LIBS. I built with Visual Studio in Release mode. I obtained two lib files in my installation directoy: blas.lib and lapack.lib.

**C++ example :** I created the following simple C++ example using the function ilaver (giving the version of lapack).

```
#include <iostream>
extern "C" { void ilaver_(int* major, int* minor, int* patch); }
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  int major = 0; int minor = 0; int patch = 0;
  ilaver_(&major, &minor, &patch);
  std::cout << major << "." << minor << "." << patch << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

**CMakeLists.txt :** I also created the associated CMakeLists file :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION "2.8.9")
project(linklapack)
enable_language(C)
enable_language(CXX)
enable_language(Fortran)
set(LAPACK_LIBDIRS "C:/softs/lapack/3.5.0/64/lib")
set(LAPACK_LIBRARIES lapack)
link_directories(${LAPACK_LIBDIRS})
add_executable(GetLapackVersion ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/GetLapackVersion.cpp)
target_link_libraries(GetLapackVersion ${LAPACK_LIBRARIES})
install(TARGETS GetLapackVersion DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX})
```

**Under Linux :** it works. (Of course by changing the path to the lib)

**Under Windows :** I launched CMake with the same compilers and the same Visual Studio configuration. I loaded the generated solution for Visual Studio and I built the "GetLapackVersion" target. Then I got the following link error :

```
2>GetLapackVersion.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ilaver_ referenced in function main
2>C:\Users\caduchon\Documents\Christophe\linklapack\BUILD\Release\GetLapackVersion.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

**Edit :** The link command in Visual Studio for the target is the following :

```
/OUT:"C:\Users\caduchon\Documents\Christophe\linklapack\BUILD\Release\GetLapackVersion.exe" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"C:/Users/caduchon/Documents/Christophe/linklapack/BUILD/Release/GetLapackVersion.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "lapack.lib" /IMPLIB:"C:/Users/caduchon/Documents/Christophe/linklapack/BUILD/Release/GetLapackVersion.lib" /MACHINE:X64 /INCREMENTAL:NO /PGD:"C:\Users\caduchon\Documents\Christophe\linklapack\BUILD\Release\GetLapackVersion.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"GetLapackVersion.dir\Release\GetLapackVersion.exe.intermediate.manifest" /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"C:/softs/lapack/3.5.0/64/lib" /LIBPATH:"C:/softs/lapack/3.5.0/64/lib/Release" /TLBID:1
```

I have no idea how to solve this problem... Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Does `dumpbin /ALL lapack.lib` show the unresolved symbol as being present?

Comment: I executed the command. I saw that the signature of the functions seems to be in uppercase. I tried with ILAVER and now I have another link problem (cannot open file 'ifconsol.lib'). So the problem to link lapack is maybe solved. Thanks for this usefull tool.

Comment: That is an Intel library. Is there a reason you are not compiling everything with the Intel compiler suite? That might alleviate some of the issues you're seeing.

Comment: I compile with CMake on several platforms. CMake generates the VS files. I'm not sure CMake can generate files for the compiler suite you talk about, and I'm not sure we can buy the licence for it. But I solved this problem, I found how to inform CMake about the intel libdir.

Comment: Well, for CMake+intel on Windows, you can generate VS project files, and then set the compiler to Intel inside the IDE. But yeah, if you only have the Fortran compiler that might be an expensive option. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question.

As rubenvb anticipated, the symbols weren't present in the library as expected. The problem is documented as "Fortran Name Mangling". In order to detect the configuration of the library with CMake, I modified my test example as following :

```
#include <iostream>
#if defined LapackNameManglingUpper
#define ilaver ILAVER
#elif defined LapackNameManglingLower
#define ilaver ilaver
#elif defined LapackNameManglingUBack
#define ilaver ilaver_
#elif defined LapackNameMangling2UBack
#define ilaver ilaver__
#elif defined LapackNameManglingUFront
#define ilaver _ilaver
#endif
extern "C" { void ilaver(int* major, int* minor, int* patch); }
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  int major = 0; int minor = 0; int patch = 0;
  ilaver(&major, &minor, &patch);
  std::cout << major << "." << minor << "." << patch << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Then, I can detect the good configuration with CMake by trying compile the code with an additional argument `-DLapackNameManglingConfig` :

```
set(NAME_MANGLING_OPTIONS
  "NameManglingUpper"
  "NameManglingLower"
  "NameManglingUBack"
  "NameMangling2UBack"
  "NameManglingUFront")
set(LAPACK_NAME_MANGLING "")
foreach(NAME_MANGLING_OPTION IN LISTS NAME_MANGLING_OPTIONS)
  set(LAPACK_NAME_MANGLING "${NAME_MANGLING_OPTION}")
  set(TRY_MANGLING_LIBRARY_DIRS ${Lapack_LIBRARY_DIRS} ${Compiler_LIBRARY_DIRS})
  set(TRY_MANGLING_LIBRARIES ${Lapack_LIBRARIES} ${Fortran_LIBRARIES})
  try_compile(TRY_MANGLING_OPTION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/tmpLapack ${CMAKE_MODULES_DIR}/GetLapackVersion.cpp
              CMAKE_FLAGS "-DLINK_DIRECTORIES=${TRY_MANGLING_LIBRARY_DIRS}" "-DLINK_LIBRARIES=${TRY_MANGLING_LIBRARIES}"
              COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "-DLapack${NAME_MANGLING_OPTION}")
  if(TRY_MANGLING_OPTION)
    set(LAPACK_NAME_MANGLING "Lapack${NAME_MANGLING_OPTION}")
    break()
  endif()
endforeach()
if(LAPACK_NAME_MANGLING STREQUAL "")
  message(SEND_ERROR "Impossible to detect Fortran name mangling...")
else()
  message(STATUS "Lapack: detected Fortran name mangling: ${LAPACK_NAME_MANGLING}")
  add_definitions("-D${LAPACK_NAME_MANGLING}")
endif()
```